# Error generating signed APK due to proguard rules

Tags: proguard, android-studio-3.3, android-r8

Generating signed APK giving error after I updated Android Studio to 3.3-rc01 and enabled R8 code shrinking.

It is giving following proguard error :

```
Error: ~/app/proguard-rules.pro, offset: 2613, line: 74, column: 7, Expected char '-' at ~/app/proguard-rules.pro:74:7
-dump class_files.txt
```

before android studio 3.3-rc01 and without R8 code shrinking it was working perfectly fine.

Any workarounds for this or I have to disable the proguard rules now.

Following is my proguard-rules.pro file

```
    # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters and InnerClass is required to use Signature.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.-KotlinExtensions


# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform


-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.unsafe.**


#Glide proguard rules
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager {
    public <init>(...);
}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-repackageclasses ''

-keep class com.qikcircle.qiketask.models.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.** {*;}
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

#removing logs
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

#for getting crash reports
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int v(...);
    public static int d(...);
}

#Crashlytics proguard rules
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you still have this error? Have you tried AS 3.3-rc02?

Comment: Yes still facing same issue even in AS 3.3-rc03 as well

Comment: Can you post your `proguard-rules.pro` file? It seems you are missing a `'-'` in a keep directive. Actually today I've tried R8 (in fullMode) and all worked fine... at least at first sight... ^_^

Comment: Is it empty because you are only use shrinking?

Comment: I have added proguard-rules.pr file

Comment: Anyway, the best way to debug this, I guess, is remove (if possibile) all the lines that give errors. One at a time until we get the next error. in this case "-dump class_files.txt" and go on until it compile the APK. And then readd one at a time the removed line and see what happens to find what's the one that gives the error. In this case our first entry point is `class_files.txt`.

Comment: I cofirm that the  [`-dump directive`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) is not supported. It throws an error. Don't know if that is an issue or is intended. But you could ask [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=Shrinker%20(R8)&authuser=0).

Comment: When I remove class_files.txt line, it generates APK successfully but the APK size is much larger so rather I disable R8

Comment: Yeah, okay. In this case you could decide still not to use R8. But that's the reason why of your question ;-]

Comment: I've open the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121340442) and they confirm they do not support it yet, but they shouldn't fail in parsing ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the [`dump directive`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) with `Proguard` (I didn't use it before) and all works fine.

```
[...]

## Strip Log.d
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}

-dump foo.txt

[...]
```

And I find my `foo.txt` under `./app/foo.txt`

```
Printing classes to [./app/foo.txt]...
```

Then I enable **R8** in **legacy mode**:

```
# For the bravests
android.enableR8=true
# For the crazyest. Must be enable also the previous setting
#android.enableR8.fullMode=true
```

And I got your error.

Without this line I can compile my APK even in **full mode** without any (apparent) issue.

So I confirm that **this directive is not supported.** Remember that R8 is still in beta. If you want you can submit an issue on the link I posted in comment.

Opened the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121340442).

Answer (score 0):

for me i had to remove the first line " public private *; " in my prograuard.pro file